# How to increment a label value when click a button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

In my iPad app.i want to increment a label value when click a button.

[image]

actually label values are sending from previous view. so now i clicked a button but the last label value was incremented.   see the below picture.

in the above picture i want to increment the label value in between the minus(-) and plus(+) buttons. but when i clicked plus button in first view but the label value is incremented on the third view.

```
 **  the above three views shown on the picture are sub viewed the scroll view **
```

i'm using this code......

```
-(IBAction)plusbutton:(id)sender
{
    val = [sender tag];
    NSLog(@"the_tag %d",val);
    itemref.countVal++;
    [self createOrderView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you
 fist give same tag value for - and + button and label in that single view so when click on the button 
 in button action

```
    NSArray *subviews=[self.scrollview subviews];  
            for(UIView *sb_local in subviews)  
                    {  
                            if(sb_local.tag==[sender tag])
                            {    

                                 if([sb_local isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                                {    
                                      UILabel *new_label=(UILabel *)[sb_local viewWithTag:pictag];  
                                      new_label.text = @"your value";
                                 //[new_label.text intValue]you get int value from that label.Increment or decrement that int value according your (+,-)button actions and assign again it to that label.
                                }

                             }
                    }
```

Please place this code in ibaction + and - buttons please give different actions for + and  - buttons in each view